# jsonp request receives 401 unauthorized

Tags: javascript, json, api, jsonp

I'm using the select2 plugin to connect with LinkedIn's company search API. What I need is for it to work with jsonp so that I can avoid the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error I get with a regular json request [I've confirmed that the json request works when I disable the default security settings in Chrome.]. By "work" I mean I want the jsonp request url to authenticate me just as the json request url is, but I continue receiving a 401 unauthorized error.

I think my problem lies with the "callback" parameter in my url set by jsonp. For instance, the LinkedIn-authenticated company-search url created by json is:

http://api.linkedin.com/v1/company-search?keywords=mcdonalds&oauth_consumer_key=xxx&oauth_nonce=xxx&oauth_signature=xxx&oauth_signature_method=xxx&oauth_timestamp=xxx&oauth_token=xxx

With jsonp it is something like:

http://api.linkedin.com/v1/company-search?callback=jQuery19107866718948353082_1365690327081&keywords=mcdonalds&oauth_consumer_key=xxx&oauth_nonce=xxx&oauth_signature=xxx&oauth_signature_method=xxx&oauth_timestamp=xxx&oauth_token=xxx

The only apparent difference is the "callback=jQuery..." parameter. Here is my JavaScript:

```
function generateUrl(term) {
    (function ($) {

    var apiKey = 'xxx';
    var apiSecret = 'xxx';
    var memberToken = 'xxx';
    var memberSecret = 'xxx';
    var action = 'GET';
    var path = 'http://api.linkedin.com/v1/company-search';
    var nonce = '1234';
    var timestamp = Math.floor((new Date()).getTime()/1000);
    var version = '1.0';
    var args = "keywords=" + term;
    // var format = 'json';

    if (args != '') { args += '&'; }
    args += "&oauth_nonce=" + nonce + "&oauth_timestamp=" + timestamp + "&oauth_version=" + version;

    OAuthSimple().reset();
    this.results = (new OAuthSimple()).sign({
      path:path,
      action:action,
      parameters:args,
      signatures:{
        'consumer_key':apiKey, 'shared_secret': apiSecret,
        'access_token':memberToken,'access_secret':memberSecret}
      }
    );

    }
    (jQuery));
    return results.signed_url.slice(results.signed_url.indexOf('?') + 1);
  }

    $("#linkedin").select2({
      placeholder: "Search for a company.",
      minimumInputLength: 1,
      allowClear: true,
      ajax: {
        url: 'http://api.linkedin.com/v1/company-search',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: function (term, page) {
          return generateUrl(term);
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
          return { results: data.companies.values };
        }
      },
      formatResult: companyFormatResult,
      formatSelection: companyFormatSelection,
      dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop_3"
  });

  function companyFormatResult(company) {
    return company.name;
  }

  function companyFormatSelection(company) {
    return company.name;
  }
```

Could it have something to do with the syntax of my url parameters? I was having problems when the "keywords" parameter wasn't immediately after "company-search?" in the normal json request, but moving the callback parameter in the jsonp request to the end of the url doesn't seem to help.

Thank you in advance.